# Featured Skills & Endorsements in SharePoint 2013 Profile

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, user-profile, user-profile-service

Is it possible to have Endorsements in SharePoint 2013 profile like linkedin?

Answer (score 0):

Anything is "possible" it all depends on your skills and abilities. Most likely it would take a developer, but you cold use the out of the box profile fields "Ask me about", Skills, and Responsibilities for this purpose.

If I were to do it I would write it as an "app" or "add-in" and then run it through a personal approval so that the permissions of the user owning the profile would allow the User Profile update to take place.